# Get new crop coordinates after rotation

Tags: image-processing, rotation, crop, jcrop

I have a site where one of the features lets users rotate/crop images. I'm using the following tools:
- Aspose for rotation
- Jcrop

before rotation to 90 or -90 the crop coordinates are correct but after rotation those coordinates are no longer.
I have tried to change the coordinates as follow :

newX -> croppingCoordinates.w - croppingCoordinates.y - 1 
newY -> croppingCoordinates.x

Note that croppingCoordinates is the jcrop coordinate resulting from "onChange" jcrop event.

Any idea where the calculation are wrong ?!!

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found i turn around that works for me, maybe it will help someone else.
it's simply by adding trueSize Jcrop property when attaching the Jcrop method to the div. So when i have a rotated image by 90 degree i simply set width = height and vice verse. like the following code snippet:

```
if (rotationDegree == 90 || rotationDegree == -90 ){
    w =  $('#myDiv').height();
    h = $('#myDiv').width();
    jQuery(function ($) {
                $('#myDiv').Jcrop({
                    onChange: showCoords,
                    keySupport: false,
                    trueSize: [w, h]
                }, function () {
                    jcrop_api = this;
                });
            }); 
}
```